Constructing a "bound method" using "unbound method" and object in Python
In the following trivial example, what is the "Pythonic" way to create a "bound" method using some_method and some_obj? (Let us assume that we cannot just use some_obj.test_method)
class Test:
    def __init__(self, some_value):
        self.some_value = some_value

    def test_method(self, arg):
        print(self.some_value, arg)

some_method = Test.test_method
some_obj = Test(1)

getattr(some_obj, some_method.__name__) seems to do the trick - but this solution is not very elegant. One could also use a lambda, but in that case the arguments for the method except self need to be specified.
Is there some simpler method to achieve this that I have overlooked?

Nothing wrong with what you’ve got, but you can also do
some_method.__get__(some_obj)


I just want to point out, you can use a lambda expression:
lambda *args, **kwargs: some_method(some_object, *args, **kwargs)

or you can use functools.partial:
functools.partial(some_method, some_object)

These would be he most idiomatic approaches, probably
